# How do I pass a username to an FTP command from the command line?

Tags: batch-file, ftp, winscp

I am attempting to script a file upload using WinSCP using a batch script. The problem is, I cannot figure out how to pass the FTP username/password to the prompt. Here is my script:

```
@echo off
"..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com" /command "option batch abort" "option confirm off" "open ftp://**.***.***.*" "put boom.txt /test/" "exit"
echo Domain\ftp_user
set /p dummy=press enter to close
```

Currently my echo command isn't working, and the command prompt still shows:

```
Prompting for credentials....
Username:
```

How do I pass a username/password to this thing?

Comment: See: http://winscp.net/eng/docs/session_url and http://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_open

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax for specifying credential in an FTP URL is:

```
ftp://username:password@hostname/
```